# How to Fetch Id of html dropdown in jQuery and Filter

Tags: jquery

I want to show the table rows according to DropdownList id selected event.
This is my html table:

```
$(function () {
        debugger
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "WebForm7.aspx/BindProjectsDatatable",
            //data: "{}",
            // data: { catid: 1 },
            data: JSON.stringify({ catid: 0 }),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (dt) {
                debugger;

                for (var i = 0; i < dt.d.length; i++) {

                    $("#tblid > tbody").append("<tr><td> <input type='checkbox' class='chk' id=" + dt.d[i].projectid + " /></td><td>" + dt.d[i].projectname + "</td><td>" + dt.d[i].Name + "</td><td>" + dt.d[i].technology + "</td><td>" + dt.d[i].projectliveurl + "</td><td><input type='image' src=" + dt.d[i].StatusImage + " onclick='actvstatus(" + dt.d[i].projectid + ", " + dt.d[i].status + ")' alt='Submit' width='18' height='18'>  </td><td>" + dt.d[i].DisplayOrder + "</td><td> <i class='ui-tooltip fa fa-pencil' onclick='btnQueryString_Click(" + dt.d[i].projectid + ")' style='font-size:22px;margin-left: 32px;'></i><i class='ui-tooltip fa fa-trash-o' onclick='deleteRecord(" + dt.d[i].projectid + ")' style='font-size: 22px;margin-left: 32px;color:red'></i> </tr>");

                }
                $("#tblid").DataTable();

            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });



    });
```

Codebehind c# code:

```
  [WebMethod]
    public static List<mProjects> BindProjectsDatatable(int catid)
    {
        clsProjectBL objcategory = new clsProjectBL();

        List<mProjects> modelCategory = new List<mProjects>();
        DataTable dtCategory = new DataTable();

        //dtCategory = objcategory.GetAllCategoryDetails("admin");
         dtCategory = objcategory.GetAllProjectDetails("admin", Convert.ToInt32(catid));
        if (dtCategory.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            modelCategory = (from DataRow dr in dtCategory.Rows
                             select new mProjects()
                             {


                                 projectid = Convert.ToInt32(dr["projectid"]),
                                 CategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CategoryID"]),
                                 projectname = dr["projectname"].ToString(),
                                 Name = dr["Name"].ToString(),
                                 technology = dr["technology"].ToString(),
                                 projectliveurl = dr["projectliveurl"].ToString(),
                                  DisplayOrder = Convert.ToInt32(dr["DisplayOrder"]),
                                 status = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["status"]),
                                 StatusImage = dr["StatusImage"].ToString(),
                                 //Deleted = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["Deleted"])
                             }).ToList();


        }
        return modelCategory;

    }
```

This is my dropdown binding jquery code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebForm7.aspx/BindCategoryDatatable",
            //data: {  },
            data: JSON.stringify({ catid: 0 }),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (r) {
                debugger;
                var ddlCustomers = $("[id=ddlCustomers]");
                ddlCustomers.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Please select</option>');
                $.each(r.d, function () {
                    ddlCustomers.append($("<option></option>").val(this['CategoryID']).html(this['Name']));
                    debugger;
                });
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("error found");
            }
        });
    });
```

This is my c# code for binding dropdown:

```
   [WebMethod]
    public static List<mCategory> BindCategoryDatatable()
    {
        clsCategoryBL objcategory = new clsCategoryBL();
        List<mCategory> modelCategory = new List<mCategory>();
        DataTable dtCategory = new DataTable();

        dtCategory = objcategory.GetAllCategoryDetails("admin");
        if (dtCategory.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            modelCategory = (from DataRow dr in dtCategory.Rows
                             select new mCategory()
                             {
                                 CategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CategoryID"]),
                                 Name = dr["Name"].ToString(),

                             }).ToList();


        }
        return modelCategory;

    }
```

I want to show the table according to the dropdownlist id.I am binding dropdown dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wording is not 100% clear but I think you are you saying you want to run the ajax which creates the table whenever an item in the dropdown list is selected. Correct me if I've misunderstood.

If that's the case then you need to handle the dropdownlist's change event:

```
$("#ddlCustomers").change(function(event) {
  //put your ajax call to populate the table in here
});
```

Alternatively, if the dropdownlist itself is created dynamically as well as the options (this is also not entirely clear from the wording) then you can't bind to it the normal way. Instead you need to use delegated events, which jQuery makes easy with the ".on" function.

```
$(document).on("change", "#ddlCustomers", function(event) {
  //put your ajax call to populate the table in here
});
```

Lastly, if you want to use the selected value of the dropdown list to pass to the server, you can change the "data" property in the ajax options to this:

```
 data: JSON.stringify({ catid: $("#ddlCustomers").val() }),
```

Comment: Sir my question is that when i select a item in dropdown list then it shows the table according to my item id..

Comment: what exactly about my example is not clear? I have written the code you need to add, and also shown you where to put your existing code within it

Comment: you already have the ajax which calls WebForm7.aspx/BindProjectsDatatable, yes? So move that inside the "change" event handler that you need to write (as per my example). Then change the "data" parameter in that existing ajax call to get the value from the dropdownlist. Literally it's just like I've already written.

Comment: can you write down details in the answer...it is too much critical to understand...I have put all the code above so you simple write down the code...

Comment: No, sorry. I don't mean to seem rude but if you won't even try to follow the simple, precise instructions that I've given, that's not my problem. I've answered the question adequately and then given you detailed help in these comments on exactly what to do with your code. I'd rather spend my time answering other questions.

Comment: where should i write down this code:$("document").on("change", "#ddlCustomers", function(event) {
  //put your ajax call to populate the table in here
});

Comment: on the next line after `$(function () {` (currently at the top of your sample). It needs to be within this because then it will bind the event handler when the page loads. If that's not something you understand already you should read up on how jQuery works

Comment: No data is binding in table

Comment: is it running this bit? `            error: function (result) {
                alert("Error");
            }` I've just noticed that the signature of this is wrong as per the jQuery docs (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). replace it with  `error: function (jQXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   alert("An error occurred whilst trying to contact the server: " + jQXHR.status + " " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
  }` and it will hopefully report the proper error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117305/discussion-between-manoj-maharana-and-adyson).

Comment: Sir i have only one question left that if i am using your code then while click on dropdown then in table, value will be shows first(depend upon the dropdown select ) and below that all the value will shows in table(That means your logic is just like sorting) ..but i want the selected value only in table...not all the values

Comment: in the last sample I gave you in chat it included the line `$("#tblid > tbody").empty();` with the "success" function (within getTableRows function). That should clear the table each time the ajax call runs, then you will only be left with the ones returned from the ajax. Make sure you've got that in your code

Comment: can you guide me any help

Comment: ask a new question and post your latest code, then it will be easier

Comment: You just tell me the possible solution

Comment: I can't without seeing your latest code. Post a new question and I (and maybe others) will be able to help you